# Как можно добавить загрузку второй миниатюры в создание/редактирование категории woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет.

Может кто-то сталкивался с таким или сможет помочь, в любом случае буду очень благодарна :)

Стоит такая задача, что нужно при создании/редактировании категории woocommerce добавить второй блок с загрузкой миниатюры. Аналогичный тому, который есть по дефолту.

Есть вариант в установке плагина ACF для создания произвольных полей, но не разумно как-то ради одного поля ставить громоздкий плагин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно поможет https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-meta-box-generator/ А вообще рекомендую забыть об ACF и использовать https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

возможно в данном случае лучше будет использовать плагин, но если очень хочется сделать без плагинов то вот пример реализации

```
class Product_Second_Thumbnail {

    private static $instance = false;

    private function __construct() {
        add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', [ $this, 'add_category_fields' ] );
        add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', [ $this, 'edit_category_fields' ], 10 );
        add_action( 'created_term', [ $this, 'save_category_fields' ], 10, 3 );
        add_action( 'edit_term', [ $this, 'save_category_fields' ], 10, 3 );
    }

    public static function get_instance() {
        return ! self::$instance ? self::$instance = new self() : self::$instance;
    }

    private function __clone() {}

    private function __wakeup() {}

    public function add_category_fields( $term ) {
        ?>

        <div class="form-field term-thumbnail-wrap">
            <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Secondary image', 'theme_domain' ); ?></label>
            <div id="product_cat_second_thumbnail" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src() ); ?>" width="60px" height="60px" /></div>
            <div style="line-height: 60px;">
                <input type="hidden" id="product_cat_second_thumbnail_id" name="product_cat_second_thumbnail_id" />
                <button type="button" class="second_upload_image_button button"><?php esc_html_e( 'Upload/Add image', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                <button type="button" class="second_remove_image_button button"><?php esc_html_e( 'Remove image', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                if ( ! jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail_id' ).val() ) {
                    jQuery( '.second_remove_image_button' ).hide();
                }

                let second_file_frame;

                jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.second_upload_image_button', function( event ) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    if ( second_file_frame ) {
                        second_file_frame.open();
                        return;
                    }

                    second_file_frame = wp.media.frames.downloadable_file = wp.media({
                        title: '<?php esc_html_e( 'Choose an image', 'woocommerce' ); ?>',
                        button: {
                            text: '<?php esc_html_e( 'Use image', 'woocommerce' ); ?>'
                        },
                        multiple: false
                    });

                    second_file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
                        let attachment = second_file_frame.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON(),
                            attachment_thumbnail = attachment.sizes.thumbnail || attachment.sizes.full;

                        jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail_id' ).val( attachment.id );
                        jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail' ).find( 'img' ).attr( 'src', attachment_thumbnail.url );
                        jQuery( '.second_remove_image_button' ).show();
                    });

                    second_file_frame.open();
                });

                jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.second_remove_image_button', function() {
                    jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail' ).find( 'img' ).attr( 'src', '<?php echo esc_js( wc_placeholder_img_src() ); ?>' );
                    jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail_id' ).val( '' );
                    jQuery( '.second_remove_image_button' ).hide();
                    return false;
                });

                jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete( function( event, request, options ) {
                    if ( request && 4 === request.readyState && 200 === request.status
                        && options.data && 0 <= options.data.indexOf( 'action=add-tag' ) ) {

                        let res = wpAjax.parseAjaxResponse( request.responseXML, 'ajax-response' );
                        if ( ! res || res.errors ) {
                            return;
                        }
                        jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail' ).find( 'img' ).attr( 'src', '<?php echo esc_js( wc_placeholder_img_src() ); ?>' );
                        jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail_id' ).val( '' );
                        jQuery( '.second_remove_image_button' ).hide();

                        return;
                    }
                } );

            </script>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    public function edit_category_fields( $term ) {

        $thumbnail_id = absint( get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'second_thumbnail_id', true ) );
        $image = $thumbnail_id ? wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $thumbnail_id ) : wc_placeholder_img_src();

        ?>

        <tr class="form-field term-thumbnail-wrap">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label><?php esc_html_e( 'Second Thumbnail', 'theme_domain' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <div id="product_cat_second_thumbnail" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $image ); ?>" width="60px" height="60px" /></div>
                <div style="line-height: 60px;">
                    <input type="hidden" id="product_cat_second_thumbnail_id" name="product_cat_second_thumbnail_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $thumbnail_id ); ?>" />
                    <button type="button" class="upload_second_image_button button"><?php esc_html_e( 'Upload/Add image', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                    <button type="button" class="remove_second_image_button button"><?php esc_html_e( 'Remove image', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    if ( '0' === jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail_id' ).val() ) {
                        jQuery( '.remove_second_image_button' ).hide();
                    }

                    let second_file_frame;

                    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.upload_second_image_button', function( event ) {

                        event.preventDefault();

                        if ( second_file_frame ) {
                            second_file_frame.open();
                            return;
                        }

                        second_file_frame = wp.media.frames.downloadable_file = wp.media({
                            title: '<?php esc_html_e( 'Choose an image', 'woocommerce' ); ?>',
                            button: {
                                text: '<?php esc_html_e( 'Use image', 'woocommerce' ); ?>'
                            },
                            multiple: false
                        });

                        second_file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
                            let attachment           = second_file_frame.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON(),
                                attachment_thumbnail = attachment.sizes.thumbnail || attachment.sizes.full;

                            jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail_id' ).val( attachment.id );
                            jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail' ).find( 'img' ).attr( 'src', attachment_thumbnail.url );
                            jQuery( '.remove_second_image_button' ).show();
                        });

                        second_file_frame.open();
                    });

                    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.remove_second_image_button', function() {
                        jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail' ).find( 'img' ).attr( 'src', '<?php echo esc_js( wc_placeholder_img_src() ); ?>' );
                        jQuery( '#product_cat_second_thumbnail_id' ).val( '' );
                        jQuery( '.remove_second_image_button' ).hide();
                        return false;
                    });

                </script>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }

    public function save_category_fields( $term_id, $tt_id = '', $taxonomy = '' ) {
        if ( ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] ) && ! isset( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce_add-tag'] ) ) ||
            ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'], 'update-tag_' . $term_id ) && ! wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce_add-tag'], 'add-tag' ) ) ||
            ! current_user_can( 'edit_term', $term_id )
        ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['product_cat_second_thumbnail_id'] ) && 'product_cat' === $taxonomy ) {
            update_term_meta( $term_id, 'second_thumbnail_id', absint( $_POST['product_cat_second_thumbnail_id'] ) );
        }
    }

}

$wc_secondary_thumbnail = Product_Second_Thumbnail::get_instance();
```

получить attachment id можно через get_term_meta( $term_id, 'second_thumbnail_id', true ), где $term_id = ID элемента таксономии. после того как у нас будет attachment id, мы можем получить ссылку на файл через функцию wp [wp_get_attachment_thumb_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_thumb_url/)

Comment: Блин дружище прям выручил. спс

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться хуками, которые есть на форму таксономии

[{Taxonomy}_add_form_fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form_fields/) 
[{Taxonomy}_edit_form_fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_edit_form_fields/) 
[created_{Taxonomy}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy/) 
[edited_{Taxonomy}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_taxonomy/)

Для woocommerce категории примерный код

```
function caterory_image_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    // вставить поле для изображения
}
add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', 'caterory_image_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );

function caterory_image_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {
 
    $t_id = $term->term_id;

    // вставить поле для изображения при редактирование категории
}
add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'caterory_image_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );

function caterory_image_save_term_fields( $term_id ) {
      
    //отправка формы и обработка загрузки изображения
}

add_action( 'created_product_cat', 'caterory_image_save_term_fields' );

add_action( 'edited_product_cat', 'caterory_image_save_term_fields' );
```